# UIWebView in UITableView Cell - WebView not filling Table Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a table view, with a static cell which has a UIWebView embedded in it.  The static cell is in the first and only section, and is the second static cell in the tableview. I am trying to dynamically change the size of the UIWebView AND UITableViewCell, based on the HTML I am passing to the loadHTMLString method.  Code below.

Within viewDidLoad:

```
[self.wbvArticle loadHTMLString:result baseURL:nil];
[self.wbvArticle setDelegate:self];
[self.wbvArticle.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[self.wbvArticle.scrollView setBounces:NO];
```

Also have the following:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        return contentHeightForCell;
    }
    else return 282;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    contentHeightForCell = [[self.wbvArticle stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];

    CGRect rect = self.wbvArticle.frame;
    rect.size.height = contentHeightForCell;
    self.wbvArticle.frame = rect;
    [self.wbvArticle sizeToFit];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

When I run this in the simulator, the table cell is sized correctly, but the webview is not. Does anyone see anything out of the ordinary? I have scoured the web and stackoverflow, but have not been able to find anything to fix it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate the height of webview and reload the table with this new height.

1) Create local variable in @interface section

```
float webViewHeight;
```

2) Then assign this height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of tableView

```
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, webViewHeight)];
```

3) Also set the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of tableview

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return webViewHeight;
}
```

4)At last calculate the height and reload tableview

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    webViewHeight = fittingSize.height;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see where I'm missing something. Just to clarify - I am utilizing a UITableView with static cells. Is this an issue for running cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I ended up changing it to Dynamic Cells, which seemed like overkill.  But it fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI. If you reload tableview in webViewDidFinishLoad: , it would running into infinite loop. Since the table reload will also reload webView it self, then after webView finish loading, it reload tableview again, and it just keeps going and going. So you may want to set some kind of flag or something else to deal with it.

Comment: This wont work. It goes to infinite loop. @user1139921, you are right we need to maintain a flag.

Answer (score 2):

Or, you may just use

```
#pragma mark - WebView Delegate
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.webViewHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```